# Why fails my internet request to Azure VM?

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-virtual-network, azure-load-balancer, azure-nsg

I have created a Linux VM with a NIC in a VNet with one subnet. This VM has no public IP due to internal policies. Now I created a Loadbalancer which has a inbound LB rule to forward Port 80 to the backend pool with my single VM. Health probe is working. I created an NSG to allow inbound traffic from Service Tag `internet` to IP adress of my VM on port 80. But accessing the public IP is not responding with nginx default page. `curl localhost` on the VM works. Anything forgotten?

Comment: Did you create a firewall rule permitting traffic on the VM itself? Have you done curl on the local VM to see if the nginx page is actually working?

Comment: Yes, curl on `localhost` works.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue was to set `source port` to `80` instead of `*`. With `source port = 80` in the NSG it's working.